# How to use an SGV in a symbol tag as a background image

Tags: css, svg

I'm trying to use an SVG from a sprite as a background image as per [this article](http://dev.webonomic.nl/unleash-the-power-of-svg-sprites). Each image in wrapped in symbol tags as per [this article](http://css-tricks.com/svg-symbol-good-choice-icons/).

My sprite.svg looks like this:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="display: none;">

    <symbol id='home' width="20" height="20" viewBox="0 0 2304 2304">
        <path d="M1728 1248v480q0 26-19 45t-45 19h-384v-384h-256v384h-384q-26 0-45-19t-19-45v-480q0-1 .5-3t.5-3l575-474 575 474q1 2 1 6zm223-69l-62 74q-8 9-21 11h-3q-13 0-21-7l-692-577-692 577q-12 8-24 7-13-2-21-11l-62-74q-8-10-7-23.5t11-21.5l719-599q32-26 76-26t76 26l244 204v-195q0-14 9-23t23-9h192q14 0 23 9t9 23v408l219 182q10 8 11 21.5t-7 23.5z" fill="#7C7C7C"/>
    </symbol>

    <symbol id='plus'>
            <path d="M13.563 5.25h-4.813v-4.813c0-0.242-0.196-0.438-0.438-0.438h-2.625c-0.242 0-0.438 0.196-0.438 0.438v4.813h-4.813c-0.242 0-0.438 0.196-0.438 0.438v2.625c0 0.242 0.196 0.438 0.438 0.438h4.813v4.813c0 0.242 0.196 0.438 0.438 0.438h2.625c0.242 0 0.438-0.196 0.438-0.438v-4.813h4.813c0.242 0 0.438-0.196 0.438-0.438v-2.625c0-0.242-0.196-0.438-0.438-0.438z" fill="#000000"></path>  
    </symbol>

</svg>
```

My HTML looks like this:

```
<a href="#" class="home-icon">Home</a>
```

And my CSS looks like this:

```
.home-icon {
    background-image: url("../img/icons/sprite.svg#home");
    height: 14px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-indent: -100px;
    width: 14px;
}
```

But it is not showing up. It did work when I used `<g>` tags as opposed to `<symbol>` but that limits me to having every image the same size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The contents of `<symbol>` tags are not directly rendered, they can only be made visible via a `<use>` tag.

You could try using an [svg fragment identifier](http://www.w3.org/TR/2003/REC-SVG11-20030114/linking.html#LinksIntoSVG) which would mean adding #svgView(viewBox(x,y,w,h)) to the image URL where x,y,w,h are your viewBox values but I think Chrome bans them for images.

Note that an inner `<svg>` tag would take a viewBox, so perhaps you should experiment with that rather than `<g>` or `<symbol>`